# how to query users that are not followed by the use in firebase firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

how to query users that are not followed by the user in firestore?
firebase structure:

```
firestore (root)
  ----users (colloection)
      ----user (doc)
         uid: "xyz"

  ----following (collection)
      ---- current users uid (doc)
         ----- following (collection)
              --- user followed (doc)
          ---- followers (collection)
              ---- users following (doc)
```

I am building `people recommended to follow like facebook`

And i want to query users that are not followed by me, is that possible, if so pls answer with the js query snippet?

I am using: firebase web 9

Comment: There is no way in Firestore to query for documents without a certain piece of information.

Comment: The [`not-in`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any)  operator is probably what you are looking for but you'll need to know IDs of users following a user. However `not-in` only combines up to 10 not equal (!=) clauses. e.g. `where(documentId(), "not-in", [follower1,...])`

Comment: I don't think `not-in` would work here @Dharmaraj. The `not-in` checks whether a specific value in the document is not equal to a number of other values. From what I can tell, there is no value in the document to search for here, so the document won't be in the index for the relevant field/values.

Comment: Yes I meant if there's any way to get an array of followers' UIDs  (from followings sub-collection) then a query on users collection might be useful (to some extent because the array size can be max 10) which would return users not following by given user in best case.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how do i exclude the users followed in the query like this
const _query = query(usersQuery, where() // <-- what should i add here in where clause, orderBy("createdAt", "desc"), limit(_limit)
      );
```

Comment: @ArnavSingh As said: this type of query is not possible on Firestore, as the items that you are looking for **don't** have a value so they aren't in the index. Check the question I linked, and the links from there for a longer explanation and some alternative data model (but I'm not sure if any apply here).